# Folium HeatMapWithTime script working on Windows, but not on Linux

Tags: python, linux, leaflet, gis, folium

This script works as expected on Windows, but when I run the exact same .py on my Linux laptop (kde neon), it produces just the map html file (as in no heatmap, no controls, no plugins).  It throws no errors on Linux, but the html produced has no heatmap, just a regular map.

Even weirder, when I run this .py script on Windows, and email the html it outputs to my Linux laptop, and open that html on Linux, that html file shows up perfectly – has the HeatMap, controls, animations, etc.

So my Linux machine can open/read/render the HeatMapWithTime fine, but it won't create it.

I'm not sure where to even start with diagnosing this.  Could this be something wrong with my Python env on the Linux laptop?  Could it be something with my OS or browser or java plugins?  Any guesses?

I've tried opening the html on Linux in both in FireFox and Brave, and like I said, it works fine if it is a copy of the html that was created on Windows, but if I run this script on Linux, that html won't work.

Here’s the script:

```
import folium
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from folium import plugins

heatmap_time_data = (np.random.random((50,20,2)) + np.array([[39, -98]])).tolist()

# dates
heatmap_time_dates = [d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in pd.date_range('20160101', periods=len(heatmap_time_data))]
# map
map_heatmap_time = folium.Map([39, -98], tiles='CartoDB Dark_Matter', zoom_start=6)
# heatmap plugin
heatmap_time_plugin = plugins.HeatMapWithTime(heatmap_time_data, index=heatmap_time_dates)
# add heatmap plugin to map
heatmap_time_plugin.add_to(map_heatmap_time)

# display map
map_heatmap_time.save('map.html')
```

I’m using conda on both computers, here’s the ymls:

**Windows 10**

```
dependencies:
  - altair=3.2.0=py36_0
  - attrs=19.3.0=py_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - certifi=2019.11.28=py36_0
  - entrypoints=0.3=py36_0
  - icc_rt=2019.0.0=h0cc432a_1
  - importlib_metadata=1.5.0=py36_0
  - intel-openmp=2020.0=166
  - jinja2=2.11.1=py_0
  - jsonschema=3.2.0=py36_0
  - markupsafe=1.1.1=py36he774522_0
  - mkl=2020.0=166
  - mkl-service=2.3.0=py36hb782905_0
  - mkl_fft=1.0.15=py36h14836fe_0
  - mkl_random=1.1.0=py36h675688f_0
  - numpy=1.18.1=py36h93ca92e_0
  - numpy-base=1.18.1=py36hc3f5095_1
  - pandas=1.0.1=py36h47e9c7a_0
  - pip=20.0.2=py36_1
  - pyrsistent=0.15.7=py36he774522_0
  - python=3.6.10=h9f7ef89_0
  - python-dateutil=2.8.1=py_0
  - pytz=2019.3=py_0
  - setuptools=45.2.0=py36_0
  - six=1.14.0=py36_0
  - sqlite=3.31.1=he774522_0
  - toolz=0.10.0=py_0
  - vc=14.1=h0510ff6_4
  - vega_datasets=0.7.0=py_0
  - vs2015_runtime=14.16.27012=hf0eaf9b_1
  - wheel=0.34.2=py36_0
  - wincertstore=0.2=py36h7fe50ca_0
  - zipp=2.2.0=py_0
  - pip:
    - branca==0.4.0
    - chardet==3.0.4
    - click==7.1.1
    - decorator==4.4.2
    - folium==0.10.1
    - future==0.18.2
    - geocoder==1.38.1
    - idna==2.9
    - ratelim==0.1.6
    - requests==2.23.0
    - urllib3==1.25.8
prefix: C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\_geo
```

**kde neon 5.18.2**

```
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=conda_forge
  - _openmp_mutex=4.5=0_gnu
  - attrs=19.3.0=py_0
  - boost-cpp=1.72.0=h8e57a91_0
  - branca=0.4.0=py_0
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h516909a_2
  - ca-certificates=2019.11.28=hecc5488_0
  - cairo=1.16.0=hfb77d84_1002
  - certifi=2019.11.28=py36h9f0ad1d_1
  - cffi=1.14.0=py36hd463f26_0
  - cfitsio=3.470=hb60a0a2_2
  - chardet=3.0.4=py36_1003
  - click=7.1=pyh8c360ce_0
  - click-plugins=1.1.1=py_0
  - cligj=0.5.0=py_0
  - cryptography=2.8=py36h72c5cf5_1
  - curl=7.68.0=hf8cf82a_0
  - expat=2.2.9=he1b5a44_2
  - fiona=1.8.13=py36h900e953_0
  - folium=0.10.1=py_0
  - fontconfig=2.13.1=h86ecdb6_1001
  - freetype=2.10.0=he983fc9_1
  - freexl=1.0.5=h14c3975_1002
  - gdal=3.0.4=py36hbb6b9fb_1
  - geopandas=0.7.0=py_1
  - geos=3.8.0=he1b5a44_1
  - geotiff=1.5.1=hcbe54f9_9
  - gettext=0.19.8.1=hc5be6a0_1002
  - giflib=5.2.1=h516909a_2
  - glib=2.58.3=py36h6f030ca_1002
  - hdf4=4.2.13=hf30be14_1003
  - hdf5=1.10.5=nompi_h3c11f04_1104
  - icu=64.2=he1b5a44_1
  - idna=2.9=py_1
  - jinja2=2.11.1=py_0
  - jpeg=9c=h14c3975_1001
  - json-c=0.13.1=h14c3975_1001
  - kealib=1.4.12=hec59c27_0
  - krb5=1.16.4=h2fd8d38_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.33.1=h53a641e_8
  - libblas=3.8.0=14_openblas
  - libcblas=3.8.0=14_openblas
  - libcurl=7.68.0=hda55be3_0
  - libdap4=3.20.4=hd3bb157_0
  - libedit=3.1.20170329=hf8c457e_1001
  - libffi=3.2.1=he1b5a44_1006
  - libgcc-ng=9.2.0=h24d8f2e_2
  - libgdal=3.0.4=h022d3c0_1
  - libgfortran-ng=7.3.0=hdf63c60_5
  - libgomp=9.2.0=h24d8f2e_2
  - libiconv=1.15=h516909a_1005
  - libkml=1.3.0=hb574062_1011
  - liblapack=3.8.0=14_openblas
  - libnetcdf=4.7.3=nompi_h9f9fd6a_101
  - libopenblas=0.3.7=h5ec1e0e_6
  - libpng=1.6.37=hed695b0_0
  - libpq=12.2=hae5116b_0
  - libspatialindex=1.9.3=he1b5a44_3
  - libspatialite=4.3.0a=hd318ce7_1036
  - libssh2=1.8.2=h22169c7_2
  - libstdcxx-ng=9.2.0=hdf63c60_2
  - libtiff=4.1.0=hc3755c2_3
  - libuuid=2.32.1=h14c3975_1000
  - libwebp=1.0.2=h56121f0_5
  - libxcb=1.13=h14c3975_1002
  - libxml2=2.9.10=hee79883_0
  - lz4-c=1.8.3=he1b5a44_1001
  - markupsafe=1.1.1=py36h8c4c3a4_1
  - munch=2.5.0=py_0
  - ncurses=6.1=hf484d3e_1002
  - numpy=1.18.1=py36h95a1406_0
  - openjpeg=2.3.1=h981e76c_3
  - openssl=1.1.1d=h516909a_0
  - pandas=1.0.2=py36h830a2c2_0
  - pcre=8.44=he1b5a44_0
  - pip=20.0.2=py_2
  - pixman=0.38.0=h516909a_1003
  - poppler=0.67.0=h14e79db_8
  - poppler-data=0.4.9=1
  - postgresql=12.2=hf1211e9_0
  - proj=6.3.1=hc80f0dc_1
  - pthread-stubs=0.4=h14c3975_1001
  - pycparser=2.20=py_0
  - pyopenssl=19.1.0=py_1
  - pyproj=2.5.0=py36he3cd046_1
  - pysocks=1.7.1=py36_0
  - python=3.6.10=h9d8adfe_1009_cpython
  - python-dateutil=2.8.1=py_0
  - python_abi=3.6=1_cp36m
  - pytz=2019.3=py_0
  - readline=8.0=hf8c457e_0
  - requests=2.23.0=py36_0
  - rtree=0.9.4=py36he053a7a_1
  - setuptools=46.0.0=py36h9f0ad1d_2
  - shapely=1.7.0=py36hc37ca83_1
  - six=1.14.0=py_1
  - sqlite=3.30.1=hcee41ef_0
  - tbb=2018.0.5=h2d50403_0
  - tiledb=1.7.0=hcde45ca_2
  - tk=8.6.10=hed695b0_0
  - tzcode=2019a=h516909a_1002
  - urllib3=1.25.7=py36_0
  - vincent=0.4.4=py_1
  - wheel=0.34.2=py_1
  - xerces-c=3.2.2=h8412b87_1004
  - xorg-kbproto=1.0.7=h14c3975_1002
  - xorg-libice=1.0.10=h516909a_0
  - xorg-libsm=1.2.3=h84519dc_1000
  - xorg-libx11=1.6.9=h516909a_0
  - xorg-libxau=1.0.9=h14c3975_0
  - xorg-libxdmcp=1.1.3=h516909a_0
  - xorg-libxext=1.3.4=h516909a_0
  - xorg-libxrender=0.9.10=h516909a_1002
  - xorg-renderproto=0.11.1=h14c3975_1002
  - xorg-xextproto=7.3.0=h14c3975_1002
  - xorg-xproto=7.0.31=h14c3975_1007
  - xz=5.2.4=h14c3975_1001
  - zlib=1.2.11=h516909a_1006
  - zstd=1.4.4=h3b9ef0a_1
prefix: /home/dan/anaconda3/envs/geo
```

Comment: Maybe this helps you out: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341004/folium-plugins-heatmapwithtime-no-longer-produces-an-output

Comment: Code is good, packages are updated, browser shows the map produced on windows. Are you sure you are opening the right file from the right path?

Comment: @jfaccioni, wow, yeah, that worked!  

For anyone having the same problem: I ran the script, then opened the html it outputs up in a text editor, searched for:

https://rawcdn.githack.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension/master/dist/leaflet.timedimension.min.js

and replaced it with:
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-timedimension@1.1.0/dist/leaflet.timedimension.min.js


Can anyone explain why that fixed it?  This kinda makes me nervous to use folium in general, tbh.  It's great that that worked, but it's a pretty janky fix...

Comment: Hi Dan, could you check if you see any errors in your browser console? (when you don't replace that url in the html)